# ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Requisition:Class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

`Questions:`

- what does it means?
- why i cannot open my form even though it has `resources requisition`?

my log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `errors' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>):
2: <div class = "well">
3:  <h2>Requisition slip</h2>
4:          <d class ="red">
5:                  <% if @requisition.errors.any? %>
6:                  <div id="error_explanation">
7:                          <h2><%=pluralize(@requisition.errors.count, "error") %>
8:prohibited this<%=@requisition.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %>

app/views/employee/_form.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_employee__form_html_erb___3453800_32433336'
app/views/employee/_content.html.erb:88:in `_app_views_employee__content_html_
erb___107804244_32353044'
app/views/employee/emain.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_employee_emain_html_erb___150956366_31927824'


Rendered  

F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered  
F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered     
F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (17.0ms)
```

Controller:

```
class RequisitionsController < ApplicationController
def new
@requisition = Requisition.new
@realasset = Realasset.new
@location = Location.new
end

def create
@requisition = Requisition.new(params[:requisition])
if @requisition.save
 Requisitionmailer.requisition_confirmation(@requisition).deliver
  if emp_signed_in?

  flash[:success] = " #{current_emp.username.capitalize} Your Requisition Submitted successfull"
  redirect_to emain_path
end
else
  if emp_signed_in?
  flash[:warning] = "Unable to send requisition try again"
  render "new"
elsif authorize_signed_in?
  flash[:warning] = "Unable to send requisition try again"
  redirect_to emain_path
  end

end
end

def show
@requisition = Requisition.find(params[:id])

end

def index
@requisition = Requisition.all
@requisition = Requisition.order("name").page(params[:page]).per(5)
 end

def destroy
@requisition = Requisition.find(params[:id])
@requisition.destroy
redirect_to requisitions_path

end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `@requisition` is nil. You can put a check like `@requisition.present?` to skip `@requisition.errors` in case it is nil.

Comment: it give `false`. i am not getting what to do

Comment: It gives false because `@requisition` is nil. What are you using it for? Where are you assigning it's value in controller? Post your controller code as well. Remove this section from code if it's not important.

Answer (score 0):

`errors` method is available for Model objects(inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base).
You are trying to access `errors` method on a `ActiveRecord:Relation` object which would be a collection of Model objects.

So, yes you would definitely get this error.

I am not sure for which action you are getting error:

If you define `@requisition` in the concerned action as:

```
@requistion = Requisition.find(params[:id])
```

or

```
@requisition = Requisition.new
```

then the current code would work.

BUT if you have defined

```
@requisition = Requisition.all ## or some other method which returns a collection ActiveRecord::Relation object
```

then you would get the error.